# "CPU is not supported" when I attempt to run .sh files on a 32bit version of Ubuntu

Tags: intel, 32-bit

I have an Ubuntu 32bit virtual machine. I am trying to install intel composer on to this machine (having downloaded it for non commercial use from the intel website). However when I try and run any of the .sh files in the package I get a message saying:

```
]$ ./install.sh
CPU is not supported.
```

I have set the file to "Allow executing file as program" in the permissions.

Could anyone give me any ideas of how I may fix this?

Thank you very much

James

Answer (score 0):

Well, it sounds like your cpu is not supported...

You can check your cpu type from the command prompt: `cat /proc/cpuinfo` This will tell you, among other things, the model of your cpu. Check to see if this matches the requirements for Intel Composer.

Check this in the host OS as well.